# Correct way to setup target/action for NSMenuItem in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsmenuitem, ibaction, nsstatusitem

I'm having some real difficulty with some initial Cocoa programming I am carrying out.

Essentially, I have an `NSStatusBar` item with an `NSMenu` attached as the menu. The menu has a single `NMMenuItem`. In IB I have connected the NSMenuItem to an `NSObject` which itself is set to the ApplicationDelegate's class; I have then set the Received Actions to an `IBAction` method in the ApplicationDelegate.  Everything is hooked up correctly I think, except when I run the program and click the menu item the `IBAction` method is not called.  I really can't seem to work it out.  Here is the relevant code.

Application Delegate h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface sssAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}

- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender;

@end
```

Application Delegate m file:

```
#import "sssAppDelegate.h"
@implementation sssAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}


- (IBAction)showPreferencePanel:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
}

@end
```

As I say, in IB I have connected the `NSMenu` to `statusMenu` in the Application Delegate (thus the menu all shows up under the `NSStatusBar`), and I have connected an `NSMenuItem` within the `NSMenu` to the `NSObject` with the Application Delegate class, and hooked it up to call showPreferencePanel, but nothing happens when I run it!!!

I tried it programatically as well but still can't get the IBAction method to be called.

Edit: I would attach some screen grabs to show the setup in IB but I'm not yet allowed.

The main nib which contains the menu that is added to the `NSStatusBar`, it looks like this:

- FO `NSApplication`
- FR `FirstResponder`
- Application `NSApplication`
- Font Manager `NSFontManager`
- Main Menu `NSMenu`

  - Menu Item (Preferences)    `NSMenuItem`
- Sss App Delegate `sssAppDelegate`

NSMenuItem:

- Sent Actions - `showPreferencePanel`--->`Sss App Delegate`

Sss App Delegate:

- Outlets - `statusMenu`--->`Main Menu`
- Received Actions - `showPreferencePanel:`--->`Main Item (Preferences)`

Comment: You mention that you created an object with the application delegate's class in the nib; is this nib the same one where you appointed the object as actually being the application delegate? If not, I'm wondering if you have created two application delegate objects by accident, which causes problems (not this one) because only one of them can really be the delegate at a time.

Comment: Have you tried logging the menu, its menu items, and the item in question's target and action? (Use `NSStringFromSelector` to convert the action selector to an NSString.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added some more to the question  which will hopefully clarify things somewhat.

Comment: I've just made a sample project, set up as you described, and everything seems to work fine for me. The status bar item appears, it contains the entire main menu, and when I select AppName>Preferences, I get a message in the log. You should stick an `NSLog` call in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` to make sure that this object really is the app's delegate. If so, the only suggestion I have is to make a sample project from scratch, containing just this functionality that you're having trouble with, to make sure that you don't miss anything and really truly do have everything hooked up properly.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, have you tried :

```
[statusItem setTarget:someTarget];
[statusItem setAction:@selector(someSelector)];
```

It should work.